# Redirect multiple sites to one

Tags: redirect, seo, search-engine, google-search, pagerank

I am in situation where there are many sites which are being merged to one. We want to redirect from former web sites to the new one but we are worried about search engine penalisation. 
Redirects from many pages with a bit different content and renks to one new.

What is good solution to get visitors to new site and transfer rank too?

addition:
There is about 5 websites which all links to one organization but differs some information. To be concrete, boy scouts, each website cowers age group within the organization. So same information are same (addresses, some names, etc.) but some differs. Their creation times also are very different first about 2001, last one 2011. They are on variety of domains and subdomains. Different authors, some use wordpress, the oldest one is almost static.

The new website does not copy pages 1:1 some merge some ignores.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Sorry, I am a developer and stackoverflow is the place where I look for answers. Should I put it somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the redirects are to relevant web pages, it isn't going to hurt and your website is not going to be penalized by Google. If you share more details about the history of the old websites that are being redirected, and the new website, I can tell you exactly if that's going to hurt.

Good solution is to do a 1:1 redirect for all the pages instead of redirecting all pages to root domain.

Comment: Added more specific info to question post.

Answer (score 0):

redirect each page from old domains to most relevant page on new site.

If you are still worried you can do a 302 redirect instead of a 301

Answer (score 0):

You Should redirect your old url from on new url so when the user clicks your url it will redirect on your new pages.